# Html Mail using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Is it possible to create & send Html Mails using GAS? The current MailApp class currently only allows string plaintext body and any html code written there displays the html source rather than rendering the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) is quite explicit, you can define html body as an optional parameter like this for example :

```
function test(){
  MailApp.sendEmail('testEmail@xx.com', 'subject :test HTML body','text Body', {htmlBody:"This is a html body test<br><br> in html format"})
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly.. Where can I get a list of all the parameters that the sendEmail method accepts?

Comment: the link I included leads to a page that shows all possible options.

Comment: Please see the docs before posting. Boths your questions are in the docs in plain sight.